# Alignment for ul on different size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem to align my `<ul>` for screen between 768px and 992. I want to align `<ul>` right in div for lg size, and on center for smaller sizes.

My code is:

```
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12 header-logo">
        <ul id="loginList" class="nav navbar-nav header-login">
            <li><a href="#" style="padding: 0">Login</a> or <a href="#" style="padding: 0;">Create account</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I use bootstrap.

Does anyone knows how to align `<ul>` on different screen size?

Comment: It is not ui, it is UL

Comment: typing error, it's <ul>. Can you help me?

Comment: Sure, but for now i,m not at my laptop. Some later bro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of display:flex and justify-content flex-end/center for this

check this snippet

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 2000px) {
  div.header-logo {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    width: 100vw;
  }
  ul {}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
  div.header-logo {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12 header-logo">
  <ul id="loginList" class="nav navbar-nav header-login">
    <li><a href="#" style="padding: 0">Login</a> or <a href="#" style="padding: 0;">Create account</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Why is not it working...what exactly you are looking for

Comment: I want to align ul on right on lg size, and center for all rest

Comment: so you the list to be on right for device widths >1200px and for others it should be center

Comment: can you check the snippet now

Comment: but when I  try this code on my application it doesn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130814/discussion-between-geeky-and-sasa).

Answer (score 0):

It has strange behavior because of class `navbar-nav`. Replace it with `navbar-default`.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row text-center">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-push-9">
   <ul id="loginList" class="nav navbar-default">
    <li><a href="#" style="padding: 0">Login</a> or <a href="#" style="padding: 0;">Create account</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```